# Pymc3 parameter estimation using custom likelihood function sampling error

Tags: theano, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc, pymc

I try to estimate parameters with a custom complex likelihood function (with 5 parameters to be estimated) using `pm.DensityDist`:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Define priors for unknown model parameters
    mu_1 = pm.Normal("mu_1", mu=0, sigma=10)
    mu_1_prime = pm.Normal("mu_1_prime", mu=0, sigma=10) 
    sigma = pm.Normal("sigma", mu=1, sigma=10)
    sigma_1 = pm.Normal("sigma_1", mu=1, sigma=10)
    alpha = pm.Normal("alpha_1", mu=1, sigma=10) 

    # Define likelihood
    def loglikelihood(dL_list, dt_list):
        res = 0
        for i in range(145):
            dL = dL_list[i]
            dt = dt_list[i]
            U1 = U1fun(dL, dt, mu_1,sigma_1,sigma)
            U2 = U2fun(dL, dt, mu_1_prime,sigma_1,sigma)
            u1 = u1fun(dL, dt, mu_1,sigma_1,sigma)
            u2 = u2fun(dL, dt, mu_1_prime,sigma_1,sigma)
            res1 = - 0.5 * np.log(1-alpha**2) - 0.5*(u1*2 + u2**2 - 2*alpha*u1*u2) / (1-alpha**2) #Copula function pdf
            res2 = - 0.5 * np.log(sigma_1**2 * dt**2 + 2 * sigma**2) - 0.5 * np.log(sigma_1**2 * dt**2 + sigma**2 * dt)
            res3 = - 0.5 * (U1**2+U2**2)
            res += res1 + res2 + res3
        return res
    
    likelihood = pm.DensityDist(
        "loglikelihood", loglikelihood, observed = {'dL_list':dL_list, 'dt_list':dt_list}) 

    # Sampling
    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(3000, step=step)
```

The custom likelihood function is quite complex, , and `dL_list` and `dt_list` are those input data. Other functions are like:

```
def normpdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1./(sigma * pm.math.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * pm.math.exp(-(x-mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
def normcdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1./2.*(1 + pm.math.erf((x-mu)/(sigma*pm.math.sqrt(2))))
def U1fun(dL, dt, mu_1,sigma_1,sigma):
    return (dL - mu_1 * dt) / (sigma_1 * dt + pm.math.sqrt(2) * sigma)
def U2fun(dL, dt, mu_1_prime,sigma_1,sigma):
    return (dL - mu_1_prime * dt) / (sigma_1 * dt + pm.math.sqrt(dt) * sigma)
def u1fun(dL, dt, mu_1,sigma_1,sigma):
    return normcdf(U1fun(dL, dt, mu_1,sigma_1,sigma),0,1)
def u2fun(dL, dt, mu_1_prime,sigma_1,sigma):
    return normcdf(U2fun(dL, dt, mu_1_prime,sigma_1,sigma),0,1)
```

But I got an error in the last row `AttributeError: 'Scratchpad' object has no attribute 'ufunc'` `Apply node that caused the error`. I don't understand the hint and tried several ways but always failed to generate sampling traces, neither find_MAP. Much appreciated if anyone could help.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\link\vm.py in __call__(self)
    312                 ):
--> 313                     thunk()
    314                     for old_s in old_storage:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\graph\op.py in rval(p, i, o, n)
    475             def rval(p=p, i=node_input_storage, o=node_output_storage, n=node):
--> 476                 r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
    477                 for o in node.outputs:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py in perform(self, node, inputs, output_storage)
    819                 else:
--> 820                     ufunc = node.tag.ufunc
    821             else:

AttributeError: 'Scratchpad' object has no attribute 'ufunc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-abc5c0bd756f> in <module>
     13 
     14     # Sampling
---> 15     start = pm.find_MAP(fmin=optimize.fmin_powell)
     16     step = pm.Metropolis()
     17     optimizer=None

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pymc3\tuning\starting.py in find_MAP(start, vars, method, return_raw, include_transformed, progressbar, maxeval, model, *args, **kwargs)
    104     else:
    105         update_start_vals(start, model.test_point, model)
--> 106     check_start_vals(start, model)
    107 
    108     start = Point(start, model=model)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pymc3\util.py in check_start_vals(start, model)
    232             )
    233 
--> 234         initial_eval = model.check_test_point(test_point=elem)
    235 
    236         if not np.all(np.isfinite(initial_eval)):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in check_test_point(self, test_point, round_vals)
   1382 
   1383         return Series(
-> 1384             {RV.name: np.round(RV.logp(test_point), round_vals) for RV in self.basic_RVs},
   1385             name="Log-probability of test_point",
   1386         )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   1382 
   1383         return Series(
-> 1384             {RV.name: np.round(RV.logp(test_point), round_vals) for RV in self.basic_RVs},
   1385             name="Log-probability of test_point",
   1386         )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1559     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1560         point = Point(model=self.model, *args, **kwargs)
-> 1561         return self.f(**point)
   1562 
   1563 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function\types.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    973             outputs = (
    974                 self.fn()
--> 975                 if output_subset is None
    976                 else self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    977             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\link\vm.py in __call__(self)
    315                         old_s[0] = None
    316             except Exception:
--> 317                 raise_with_op(self.fgraph, node, thunk)
    318 
    319 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\link\utils.py in raise_with_op(fgraph, node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    506         # Some exception need extra parameter in inputs. So forget the
    507         # extra long error message in that case.
--> 508     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_trace)
    509 
    510 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\link\vm.py in __call__(self)
    311                     self.thunks, self.nodes, self.post_thunk_clear
    312                 ):
--> 313                     thunk()
    314                     for old_s in old_storage:
    315                         old_s[0] = None

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\graph\op.py in rval(p, i, o, n)
    474             # default arguments are stored in the closure of `rval`
    475             def rval(p=p, i=node_input_storage, o=node_output_storage, n=node):
--> 476                 r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
    477                 for o in node.outputs:
    478                     compute_map[o][0] = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\elemwise.py in perform(self, node, inputs, output_storage)
    818                     ufunc = self.ufunc
    819                 else:
--> 820                     ufunc = node.tag.ufunc
    821             else:
    822                 ufunc = node.tag.ufunc

AttributeError: 'Scratchpad' object has no attribute 'ufunc'
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{add,no_inplace}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (((Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) / i4) + (sqr((i0 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3))) / i4)) - ((i0 * i6 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3)) / i4)))}}.0, ...... Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (((Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) / i4) + (sqr((i0 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3))) / i4)) - ((i0 * i6 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3)) / i4)))}}.0, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (((Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) / i4) + (sqr((i0 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3))) / i4)) - ((i0 * i6 * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i2, i3) * Composite{erfc(((i0 * i1) / i2))}(i1, i5, i3)) / i4)))}}.0, Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0)
Toposort index: 442
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, scalar)]
Inputs shapes: [(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
Inputs strides: [(), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
Inputs values: [array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973), array(nan), array(0.89587973)]
Outputs clients: [[Elemwise{sub,no_inplace}(Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: Seems like important parts of the code are missing. E.g., what is `loglikelihood`? Also, `observed` are usually values, not samples from a model's RVs. Please add details and/or try creating a simplified example (e.g., single parameter custom density) that also fails.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @merv! I've added the codes for my `loglikelihood` function above, the formula is quite complex but the idea is just to maximize this likelihood to estimate those 5 unknown parameters. And for the `observed` , I put those five parameters cuz they are the variables for my likelihood function, but not sure it's the right way we can do that...